# Как передать значение в форму 1С?

Tags: 1с

У меня есть массив ролей. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы открылась форма создания профиля группы доступа и в ней были выбраны роли из массива (чтобы стояли галочки).

Форму можно открыть и передать в нее массив так:

```
ПараметрыФормы = Новый Структура("КоллекцияРолей", МассивРолей);
ОткрытьФорму("Справочник.ПрофилиГруппДоступа.Форма.ФормаЭлемента", ПараметрыФормы);
```

Но есть два вопроса. В какой именно реквизит нужно передать роли? В `КоллекцияРолей`?

Если я правильно понял, что в коллекцию ролей, то как тогда преобразовать массив в таблицу значений. Так как `КоллекцияРолей` - это таблица значений.

Написал такой код, но вылетает ошибка и пишет, что итератор не определен.

```
Функция ПреобразоватьМассивВТаблицуЗначений(мсДанные) Экспорт

    тзДанные = Новый ТаблицаЗначений;

    Для Каждого ЭлементМассива Из мсДанные Цикл
        // Рисуем колонки для таблицы

        Если тзДанные.Колонки.Количество() = 0 Тогда
            Для Каждого ЗначениеСтруктуры Из ЭлементМассива Цикл
                тзДанные.Колонки.Добавить(ЗначениеСтруктуры.Ключ);
            КонецЦикла;
        КонецЕсли;

        // Добавляем данные в таблицу

        НоваяСтрока = тзДанные.Добавить();
        Для Каждого ЗначениеСтруктуры Из ЭлементМассива Цикл
            НоваяСтрока[ЗначениеСтруктуры.Ключ] = ЗначениеСтруктуры.Значение;
        КонецЦикла;

    КонецЦикла;

    Возврат тзДанные;

КонецФункции
```

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что если передадите в "КоллекцияРолей" свои данные, то там будут проставлены галочки?

Comment: @Sagittarius а как их можно проставить?

Comment: Для начала нужно понять, как работает этот механизм. Каким образом роли там появляются и что происходит, когда оператор ставит галочки. Поняв механику, можно уже будет понимать, как именно дорабатывать.

Comment: Бегло осмотрел реквизит формы, который вы описываете, саму форму и понял, что не по тому пути вы идете. Если вы туда свой массив даже и передадите, то ничего не заполнится. Не для этого он нужен на форме.

Answer (score 0):

Эта задача решается в два этапа:

1. Передать параметры в форму - с этой частью Вы справились
2. Обработать параметры внутри формы ! Для этого открываем модуль Формы ищем процедуру *ПриСозданииНаСервере*; Если конфигурация недоступна для редактирования, добавляем свой код в Расширение;

&НаСервере

```
Процедура ПриСозданииНаСервере(Отказ, СтандартнаяОбработка)
  Если Параметры.Свойство("КоллекцияРолей") Тогда
    // Добавляем в ТЗ формы данные из переденного параметра
  КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры
```